# Error: No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

I'm not an expert in Visual Studio code. I have this error when trying to rebuild the project:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
No resource identifier found for attribute 'overlaySurface' in package 'com.fleeped.messenger'  Fleeped  C:\Users\-\Desktop\Messenger\Resources\layout\TwilioVideoCallActivityLayout.axml   2
```

Any ideas how to fix this please?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activity_video_chat_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/secound_color"
    >
...
```

Comment: Please include the part of code that causing this error which I beliew is TwilioVideoCallActivityLayout.axml also if you are trying to compile a library or code that you downloaded from somewhere, include link to original source.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_video_chat_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/secound_color">

Comment: I suspect you have a missing resource called overlaySurface which is missing, it can be an XML or anything but I don't see it in the xml you have included, part of that XML is missinge too. Also please edit your question and add the XML to it